# Using UISlider to change CALayer values

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, calayer, user-defined-functions, uislider

hoping someone can help out on this one. I'm trying to use a UISlider to change the values in a CA Sublayer. Been working on it for a few days but can't seem to figure it out. Camera is running fine, slider is moving but connection  is missing somewhere..!

Ps. relatively new to this, so step-by-step advice would be appreciated :-)

Thank you!

.h File:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface AVViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider*mySlider;

- (IBAction)adjustValue:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m File from @implementation line:

```
@implementation AVViewController

@synthesize mySlider;

- (IBAction)adjustValue:(UISlider *)sender {
float value = [(UISlider *)sender value];
if (value <0) value = 0;
if (value >0) value = 1;
mySlider.value = value;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];

NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *frontCamera = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            frontCamera = device;
            break;
        } 
}

NSError *error = nil;    
AVCaptureDevice *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontCamera error:&error];
    [session addInput:input];

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[previewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 290 , 350)];
previewLayer.cornerRadius = 100.0;
[rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];

CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
sublayer.frame = CGRectMake (15,15,previewLayer.bounds.size.width,previewLayer.bounds.size.height);
//VALUES TO BE ADJUSTED WITH UI SLIDER
sublayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:mySlider.value].CGColor;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer];

[session startRunning];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to connect the the slider's value changed event to your IBAction.
- You also need to keep instance to your sublayer so you can refer to it from outside of `viewDidLoad`.

In `viewDidLoad` add:

```
   // Call adjustValue: when the slider value changes
   [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(adjustValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

   // create and configure sub layer
   ...
   self.mysublayer = sublayer;
```

Then in the `IBAction` you can modify your layer:

```
- (IBAction)adjustValue:(UISlider *)sender {
    float value = [sender value];
    // Modify layer here.
    self.mysublayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:value].CGColor;

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful indeed & now happy to see it working. Thanks again :)